# Kendo UI Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, razor, grid, kendo-ui, actionlink

I'm using `Kendo UI Grid` with an action link into a client-template column. This action link call an data edit view. See example:

```
 c.Bound(p => p.sID).ClientTemplate(@Html.ImageActionLink(Url.Content("~/Content/images/edit3.png"), "Edit", "Edit", new { id = "#= sID #" }, new { title = "Edit", id = "Edit", border = 0, hspace = 2 }).ToString()
                           ).Title("").Width(70).Filterable(false).Groupable(false).Sortable(false);
```

My question is how can I configure the grid in order to show an ajax loader when the action link is clicked, until the edit view is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

you can create relative div and insert there your grid and loader wrapper:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="loading-wrapper">
        <div class='k-loading-image loading'></div>
        <!-- k-loading-image is standart kendo class that show loading image -->
    </div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid()....)
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.loading-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4em;  
    top: 50%;
}
```

add to imageActionLink in htmlAttributes object class named "edit" (for example), and write click event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
    $('.loading-wrapper').show();
    $.ajax({
        // ajax opts    
        success: function(response) {
             // insert your edit view received by ajax in right place
             $('.loading-wrapper').hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like :

```
c.Bound(p => p.sID).Template(@<a href=\"YourLink\@item.sID\">Edit</a>).Title("Edit").Encoded(false); 
//encoded false = Html.Raw
```